# How to Generate random images through numbers c#?

Tags: c#, image, random, numbers, jpeg

I am making an app in which 4 chits are to be thrown randomly. I am done with generating random numbers by clicking on a button random numbers are generated between 1 to 4.

My question is how do I associate the 4 images with those numbers? Suppose if 1 comes randomly  - then 1.jpg should be displayed. My programming language is c# and working in Visual studio 2012.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page

{

   Random rand = new Random();

 public MainPage()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int num=rand.Next(1,5);
        textblock1.Text=num.ToString();
    }}}
```

***i m showing the numbers in a textblock .now i have 4 images which i have to display randomly.,my question is how and where to display them .***

Comment: What is a chit? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What sort of app are you writing? Windows? Web? What have you tried? Show some code.

Comment: its's an indian game app in which we have to throw 4 chits .

Comment: @RichardEv a chit is a piece of paper, 4 pieces of paper are there and i have to throw it randomly , i have generated random numbers till now  , for 4 chits we can take 4 image, my question is how to display random images and where to display them , suppose if 1 is generated randomly then 1.jpg should be shown .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done used this method

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int dice = rand.Next(1, 5);

        switch (dice)
        {
            case 1:

                Image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/1.png"));

                break;
            case 2:

                two.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/2.png"));
                break;
            case 3:

                three.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/3.png"));
                break;
            case 4:

                four.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/4.png"));
                break;

        }

    }for bitmap image refrence will be "using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just substitute the generated number to a file name like:

```
string.Format("{0}.jpg", generatedNumber);
```

Very little code, no 'if' or 'switch' needed.

I would also make a separate component (I)FileNameResolver that contains the logic to determine the correct file name and error handling; and use that one in your code.

Comment: good because it works whatever value `generatedNumber` has (until the file is accessed), bad for the same reason.

Comment: additionaly, string manipulation is a slow way of generating the file name but I doubt it would be a performance issue.

Comment: no you could still use very simple exception handling on generated number value beforehand.

Comment: performance issue? Are you calling this millions of times then? Performance is no issue unless you work in a special environment where milliseconds matter. See http://ludwigstuyck.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/formatting-strings/

Comment: Judging from the question I doubt the performance would be a problem. However, constraining the arguments and finding any bugs as soon as possible might be.

Comment: care to explain your concern?

Comment: What do you mean with show? Is it a web app, windows app, ...?

Comment: @L-Three show means how to display and where to display it , its a win 8 application.please can u give more simple explanation, coz m a beginner.

Comment: Did you already look for a tutorial or book on writing windows 8 apps?

Comment: @L-Three ya i looked but got no help :-(

Comment: http://www.appsurfer.com/apps/16-raja-mantri-chor-sipahi see this one lyk this game i have to implement

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
Random rand = new Random();

Bitmap GetRandomImage(){
    Bitmap bmp;
    int n = rand.Next(0, 4);

    if(n == 0)
       bmp = new Bitmap("mypath1");
    else if(n == 1)
       bmp = new Bitmap("mypath2");
    else if(n == 2)
       bmp = new Bitmap("mypath3");
    else
       bmp = new Bitmap("mypath4");

    return bmp;
}
```

Or you can rename your files and use something like:

```
Random rand = new Random();

Bitmap GetRandomImage(){
    int n = rand.Next(0, 4);

    return new Bitmap(string.Format("mypath\\{0}.jpg", n));
}
```

Comment: where to display that image ?

Comment: If it's a winform application, I'd suggest you to use a [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: it's not a winform application , its a windows 8 application blank app .xaml one

Answer (score 0):

Random rand = new Random();
                int randomPosition = rand.Next(0, 9);

```
            lblEnglish.Text = sw.EnglishHeartSentence[randomPosition];
            lblShona.Text = sw.shonaSentence[randomPosition];
            switch (randomPosition)
            {
                case 0:
                    mainPicBox.Image = Funda_isizulu_.Properties.Resources.diarrhea_900x600px;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mainPicBox.Image = Funda_isizulu_.Properties.Resources.hunger1; ;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mainPicBox.Image = Funda_isizulu_.Properties.Resources.stomachache1;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    mainPicBox.Image = Funda_isizulu_.Properties.Resources.full_clipart_1;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    mainPicBox.Image = Funda_isizulu_.Properties.Resources.Top_10_Foods_To_Relieve_Menstrual_Cramps_1;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    mainPicBox.Image = Funda_isizulu_.Properties.Resources.preg;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    mainPicBox.Image = Funda_isizulu_.Properties.Resources.belly;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    mainPicBox.Image = Funda_isizulu_.Properties.Resources.a_man_with_visible_spine_holds_his_back;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    mainPicBox.Image = Funda_isizulu_.Properties.Resources.bell;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    mainPicBox.Image = Funda_isizulu_.Properties.Resources.coffee_growl_905;
                    break;

            }
```

Answer (score -1):

er,

```
switch (number)
{
    case 1:
        return "1.jpg";
    case 2:
        return "2.jpg";
    case 3:
        return "3.jpg";
    case 4:
        return "4.jpg";
    default:
        throw ArgumentException("number");
}
```

---

it all depends really,

how about,

```
private static readonly WhateverTypeMyImagesNeedToBe[] images =
    {
        new WhateverTypeMyImagesNeedToBe("1.jpg"),
        new WhateverTypeMyImagesNeedToBe("2.jpg"),
        new WhateverTypeMyImagesNeedToBe("3.jpg"),
        new WhateverTypeMyImagesNeedToBe("4.jpg")
    }

private static WhateverTypeMyImagesNeedToBe GetRandomImage()
{
    return images[new Random().Next(0, images.Length)];
}
```

Comment: @JoeB why am I getting this weird exception, I hate the guy who wrote this.

Comment: @JoeB `12312321` is somewhat higher than the `4` specified in the question. I'd suggest the 12312321st image may not be present on the disk. Is it better for for users to wait for the `File.Open` operation to fail so that you can not hate your job?

Comment: @Jodrell when i m writing switch code it says "a return keyword must not be followed by an object xpression"